# Evective way of getting list from tree leafs in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

I have data structure looking something like this (tree):

```
[{'children': [{'children': [{'id',*}, {'id',*}, *], * }, *] },{'children': [], *}, {*}]
```

I want extract list of id's from it. I do it this very basic way:

```
l = []
for i in some_tree:
    for j in i['children']:
        for k in j['children']:
            l.append(k['id'])
```

how can I do it:

a) better in terms of algorithimic efiiciency

b) more pythonic, e.g list comprehensions, or some extra tricks like zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can straight away change it to List comprehension, like this

```
[k['id'] for i in some_tree for j in i['children'] for k in j['children']]
```

If you want more idiomatic

```
from operator import itemgetter
children = itemgetter("children")
[k['id'] for i in some_tree for j in children(i) for k in children(j)]
```

Comment: how about efficiency?

Comment: @andi and I believe LC is the maximum optimization you can do... :(